# Как сделать так, чтобы по каждому нажатию кнопки последовательно отображался каждый элемент массива?

Tags: javascript, html, css, массивы, button

```js
let phrases = [
    {text:'Текст1'},
    {text:'Текст2'},
    {text:'Текст3'},
    {text:'Текст4'},
    {text:'Текст5'}
];

let button = document.querySelector('.button');
let phrase = document.querySelector('.phrase');

button.addEventListener('click', function () {
    for (let count = 0; count < phrases.length; count++) {
        phrase.innerText = phrases[count].text
    }
})
```

```css
body {
    background-color: rgba(40, 39, 39, 1);
    color: white;
}

.header {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
}

.button {
    width: 175px;
    height: 55px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 200px;
    bottom:100px;
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-top: 450px;
    margin-left: 1100px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: opacity 0.2s;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid white;
}

.buttontext {
    position: absolute;
    right: 255px;
    top:290px;
    font-family: Russo One;
    font-size: 25px;
}

.phrase {
  position: absolute;
  left: 30px
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
    <head>
        <script src="js.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css" type="text/css"/>
       <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
    <title>Title</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="keywords" content="Keywords">
        <meta name="description" content="Content">
    </head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
    <h1 class="logo">Logo</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="buttontext">
        Button
    </div>
    <div class="button">
    </div>
    <div class="advice">
        <span class="phrase">
            Место отображения текста
        </span>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

В общем, есть код, есть кнопка, есть массив. Я хочу, чтобы после каждого нажатия отображался один элемент массива (последовательно). У меня получилось сделать последовательное отображение, но оно работает неправильно. Дело в том, что всего лишь при одном нажатии на кнопку поочередно начинают отображаться все элементы массива без остановки (он останавливается только тогда, когда цикл становится более длинным, чем массив (имею ввиду count < phrases.length)).
Буду очень благодарен любой помощи!
P.S
html/css я упростил. У меня на сайте последовательно выводятся все элементы массива по порядку без остановки, но когда я написал код сюда, то тут он работает по другому (выводиться только последнее значение массива).
Но, в любом случае, мне нужно, чтобы при каждом нажатии выводилось одно значение массива по порядку. Ещё раз, заранее, огромное спасибо за любую помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вы не сохраняете последний элемент, который был добавлен.

```js
const phrases = [
    {text:'Текст1'},
    {text:'Текст2'},
    {text:'Текст3'},
    {text:'Текст4'},
    {text:'Текст5'}
];

const button = document.querySelector('.button');
const phrase = document.querySelector('.phrase');

let currentActiveIndex = 0;

button.addEventListener('click', function () {
    if (currentActiveIndex < phrases.length) {
      phrase.innerText = phrases[currentActiveIndex].text;
      currentActiveIndex = currentActiveIndex + 1;
    }  
})
```

```css
body {
    background-color: rgba(40, 39, 39, 1);
    color: white;
}

.header {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
}

.button {
    width: 175px;
    height: 55px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 200px;
    bottom:100px;
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-top: 450px;
    margin-left: 1100px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: opacity 0.2s;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid white;
}

.buttontext {
    position: absolute;
    right: 255px;
    top:290px;
    font-family: Russo One;
    font-size: 25px;
}

.phrase {
  position: absolute;
  left: 30px
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
    <head>
        <script src="js.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css" type="text/css"/>
       <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
    <title>Title</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="keywords" content="Keywords">
        <meta name="description" content="Content">
    </head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
    <h1 class="logo">Logo</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="buttontext">
        Button
    </div>
    <div class="button">
    </div>
    <div class="advice">
        <span class="phrase">
            Место отображения текста
        </span>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное, спасли! Галочка ваша.